# Azure logic apps if statement

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams, azure-logic-apps

I'm building an app which basically checks if ad user was fired by HR if it was it sends teams message with 3 options. The options are delete user , disable user and do nothing with the user. After administrator clicks on appropriate option the teams sends another message with confirmation that it was done and what option was used for that action.

So the problem is I can only make an if statement to return only 2 of 3 options. Is there away to make it check all 3 options and return only one which was used ?

The submitActionId is always correct when I click on the options

Here is my if statement `if(equals(body('KDVPRequestUserDelete')['submitActionId'], 'Confirm'),'Delete','Disabled')`

My teams action button looks like this:

```
"actions": [
    {
        "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Ištrinti",
        "style": "positive",
        "id": "Confirm",
        "data": 1,
        "iconUrl": "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-style-svg-icons-part-1/512/cancel_delete_remove_stop-512.png"
    },
    {
        "horizontalAlignment": "Right",
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Išjungti",
        "style": "positive",
        "id": "Change",
        "data": 2,
        "iconUrl": "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/leto-arrows-1/64/_cancel_disable-256.png"
    },
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Nedaryti nieko",
        "id": "Nothing",
        "data": 3,
        "iconUrl": "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-messaging-ui-color-line/254000/172-512.png"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to nest an [if](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#if) statement in the if statement, for example:

```
if(equals(2, 1), 'yes', if(equals(1, 1), 'yes', 'no'))
```

If 2 is equal to 1, return yes, if it is not true, continue to compare 1 equal to 1, if it is true, return yes, if it is not true, return no.